# tilde mark over letters in exponents or subscripts in math mode under revtex4-1

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts, tilde

A space between the tilde mark and a letter is relatively higher in exponent or subscript in math mode. For instance, the tilde mark appears differently spaced over the letter z in the two following situations: `$B_{\tilde{z}}$` and `$\tilde{z}$`. How to solve this problem?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,11pt,draft,onecolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amscd,stmaryrd}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,url}

\usepackage[nonscript]{accents}

\begin{document}

\(\tilde{z}\)
\(B_{\tilde{z}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  In your case, please also tells which engine (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`) you are using to compile the document

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I Use TeXshop but the problem originates from the "accents" package. I use the command \underaccent{...} and another command for similar result would be useful in replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the `accents` manual:

> `nonscript single`
>
> These package options are intended mainly for speeding up the typesetting of document. The algorithm used here is recursive and very slow; although in fast processors that is not felt, in slow system that could be very annoying.
>
> **single** If you are interested only in `\accentset`. Accents are not reimplemented.
>
> **nonscript** If you intend to use multiple accents in text and display modes only.

The correct phrase should be ‘in text and display styles only’; the meaning is that with the `nonscript` option accents will *not* work correctly when used in subscripts.

So remove the `nonscript` option and you'll get

[image]